# where is eclipse dropins folder

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, google-java-format

i just downloaded eclipse 2019-03 (4.11.0), and need to install google-java-format plugin, according to the instruction I need to put the google-java-format Eclipse plugin to eclipse dropins folder, i looked around there is no such a folder, by google around I decided to manually create this folder now the folder directory looks like this

```
/Users/ddd/eclipse/java-2019-03
                               /Eclipse.app
                               /dropins
                                  google-java-format-eclipse-plugin_1.6.0.jar
```

then i restart eclipse and tried to configure the java code formatter to use google java format: 
[image]

seems like the plugin was not picked up by eclipse, did I put the dropins folder at the wrong place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On macOS it is inside the Eclipse.app in the 'Contents/Eclipse' folder alongside the features and plugins folders. In Finder you have to use 'Show Package Contents' on the Eclipse application to see the folder structure inside the app.
[image: dropins folder]